# I was hoping to get this functionality. Any suggestions of how i can make this work

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to add add some functionality to array prototype am not able to make it work as expected.

```
interface Array<T> {
    getBy: T extends object ? <P extends keyof T>(value: T[P], prop: P) => T | null : (value: T) => T | null;
}

Array.prototype.getBy = getType;


function getType<T>(this: T[], value: T): T | null
function getType<T extends object, P extends keyof T>(this: T[], value: T[P], prop: P): T | null
function getType<T, P extends keyof T>(this: T[], value: T | T[P], prop?: P, ) {
    if (prop) {
        return this.filter(item => item[prop] === value)[0] || null;
    } else {
        return this.filter(item => item === value)[0]
    }
};

const someArray = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
const complexArray = [{ a: 1, b: 200 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
const primArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(primArray.getBy(1));
console.log(someArray.getBy(3, 'a'));
// console.log(complexArray.getBy(200, 'a')); Throws error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `complexArray` has a union type. When you use a conditional type over a union type the conditional type will distribute over the members of the union. So `getBy` will end up being a union of function signatures, which by definition is not callable.

The simplest solution is not to use conditional types, overloads would work better in this case:

```
interface Array<T> {

    getBy<T>(this: T[], value: T): T | null
    getBy<T extends object, P extends keyof T>(this: T[], value: T[P], prop: P): T | null
}

Array.prototype.getBy = getType;


function getType<T>(this: T[], value: T): T | null
function getType<T extends object, P extends keyof T>(this: T[], value: T[P], prop: P): T | null
function getType<T, P extends keyof T>(this: T[], value: T | T[P], prop?: P, ) {
  if (prop) {
      return this.filter(item => item[prop] === value)[0] || null;
  } else {
      return this.filter(item => item === value)[0]
  }
};

const someArray = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
const complexArray = [{ a: 1, b: 200 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
const primArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(primArray.getBy(1));
console.log(someArray.getBy(3, 'a'));
console.log(complexArray.getBy(200, 'a'));
```